# How to disable Lazy Load in hibernate..?

Tags: hibernate

When i click on button then it calls the getter() and setter() method of the bean and load the values for all fields, is there any other way to set the value of fields without clicking on button or on loading of same page.

Comment: What's the mapping type M2M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have either

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

or

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

and similarly for `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany`.

The former will load the collection whenever this object is loaded; the latter will load it lazily.

But note that **lazy loading is the default**, so if you haven't specified either, then you'll get lazy loading. It sounds as though you want to specify eager loading for your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can issue an hQL query and use the fetch join mechanism. (Note: this approach does not require you to change the OR mapping)

good news: you can even keep the existing object references as long as you issue the fetch join query inside the current hibernate session